# Intellij IDEA: sbt compile is ok in the command but why build.sbt is highlighted in red？

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-plugin

I want to learn and compile the [project](https://github.com/opendiffy/diffy),but the build.sbt is highlighted in red when import with Intellij IDEA 2020.02.
[image: cannot resolve symbol]
[image]

But compiling on the command line can succeed and invalidate cahce does not work.
[image: sbt compile success]
And my project structure is
[image: project structure]

Comment: Have you added the Scala framework to your project, if you imported it from somewhere else?

Comment: Have you imported build as sbt build or e.g. bsp build? When you open quick goto command is there more than one build.sbt?

Comment: In my experience this just happens, with no reason. Often reloading the sbt project helps.

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart this should work as @Suma said it happens for no reason.

Comment: @Suma It does not work, I have tried.

Comment: @user No,I did not add the scala framework for my project and do not know the framework in my project.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I don't quite understand what you mean but there is only one build.sbt in my project.

Comment: Verify if you see a Scala SDK in your project settings. (There is no such think as Scala framework or Scala facet any more, you can find about them in older guides, but nothing like this exists in recent version, only Scala SDK). Can  you show what you see in your Project structure after the SBT import?

Comment: @Toni.W sbt doesn't support symlinks so if you store your workspace on symlinked folder, then what sbt outputs as your project files might have different paths than your local files. Then you can see two `build.sbt` in IntelliJ where one is displayed is whole red, and the other one is parsed correctly.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok oh,there are two build.sbt files of, and one is in root folder but the other is in project folder.

Comment: Does it look like [that issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/4552)?